# Bot Blacklists Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to find out how to blacklist people using a json file and checking if the user id is in the file. So far, this is my code:

```
import json

with open("ids.json", "r") as f:
    ids = json.load(f)

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
   if ctx.message.author.id in ids:
    await ctx.send('Unfortunately, you have been blacklisted from the bot. If you wish to know why or appeal, join this server: ')
   else:
    #do stuff here
```

But it isn't working. There's no error, yet it still lets me use the commands. How do I fix this, and what's wrong with my current code?

In my json file:

```
["713780345035817022", "701792352301350973"]
```

Comment: Is that the exact indentation used in your code? The `if` and `else` are not on the same level. And the `await ctx.send` should be one level back from the `if`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I messed up the spacing in my question, but it is not the exact indentation in my code.

Comment: `ctx.author.id` is an int, you should convert it to a str because checking if it's in ids: `if str(ctx.author.id) in ids`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why its not getting information from the json file is because the IDs are strings, not integers. `ctx.message.author.id` is classed as an integer. Integers are mostly whole numbers. `print(12345)` is an example, and integers don't use quotation marks.

On the other hand, strings do require quotes (e.g `print("This is a string")`). `["713780345035817022", "701792352301350973"]` includes strings instead of integers, so if you want to blacklist a user, you're most likely going to want to remove the double quotation marks, and convert them into integers.

I don't see much/any other errors, but its just that you might be confusing integers with strings. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the system I use. Oh, and make a json file called muted.json and type `{}` inside that file. Make sure that the file is in the same directory as the bot python file.

```
async def open_muted(user):

  users = await get_muted_data()

  if str(user.id) in users:
    return False
  else:
    users[str(user.id)] = {}
    users[str(user.id)]["mute"] = 0

    


  with open("muted.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(users,f)
  return True

async def get_mute(user):
    
    await open_muted(user)
    users = await get_muted_data()

    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]['mute']
    return wallet_amt

async def get_muted_data():
  with open("muted.json") as f:
    users = json.load(f)

  return users

async def add_mute(user):
    
    await open_muted(user)
    
    users = await get_muted_data()

    users[str(user.id)]['mute'] += 1

    with open("muted.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

async def remove_mute(user):
    
    await open_muted(user)
    
    users = await get_muted_data()

    users[str(user.id)]['mute'] -= 1

    with open("muted.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def blacklist(ctx,user:discord.Member, *,reason=None):
    if await get_mute(user) == 0:
      await add_mute(user)
      await ctx.send("{} has blacklisted {} for : {}".format(ctx.author.name, user.name, reason))
    else:
      await ctx.send("The person is already blacklisted.")

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def unblacklist(ctx,user:discord.Member, *,reason=None):
    if await get_mute(user) != 0:
      await remove_mute(user)
      await ctx.send("{} has unblacklisted {} for : {}".format(ctx.author.name, user.name, reason))
    else:
      await ctx.send("The person is already unblacklisted.")

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
        await ctx.send("You are not allowed to use this command")
    else:
        #do stuff
```

Just ask me questions if you feel confused.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your IDs in the json file are strings. `ctx.message.author.id` is an int.

To address this problem you could convert your IDs into integers instead:
`[713780345035817022, 701792352301350973]` inside of your json file.

Answer (score 0):

You are keeping the ID's of the users as string in the list, as everyone has said. The easiest fix for this would be to change the

```py
with open("ids.json", "r") as f:
    ids = json.load(f)
```

to:

```py
with open("ids.json", "r") as f:
    ids = json.load(f, parse_int=int)
```

so that your list would be a list of integers.